# Neural Network overfitting and underfitting problem for wifi triangulation

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am currently having a problem with my network, it either overfits with the training data so i tried to solve the problem by applying dropout layers to all my hidden layers. This in turn made it so my network is now underfitting and never getting all the neurons passed a MSE of 0.1. The network itself isn't that big with a brief description below.

> My question is how would i solve this problem of underfitting and
>   overfitting?

Network structure: 100 -> 30 -> 30 -> 3

I am working with wifi signals  and the input value is equal to the strength. The input for the network coresponds to the signal strength of my given routers.
The input values would be the following:

```
1: good signal
0: bad signal
-1: no signal
```

The following picture shows the training for the network without dropout neurons (overfitting) `MSE of single` is the MSE for one specific training value from my training set.

[image]

Results of running testing data within the network:

[image]

Same Structured network but with dropout at 5%:

[image]

Both were running for 100000 iterations.
I am using stochastic gradient descent with a batch size of 15 training values each iteration and a total amount of training data of 240.

```
Function being used tanh.

Dropout probability used: 10%, 20%, 50%

Network Sizes tried before:

 - 100, 10, 3 
 - 100, 50 ,25, 10 ,3
 - 100, 100, 100, 3
 - 100, 12, 3 = best so far
 - 100 , 3
```

> I just do not get a good result on my testing data. I would be very
>   happy if someone could help me with this to increase the accuracy of
>   my network on the testing data.

Comment: The fact that you applied dropout doesn't really tell much unless you specify dropout probability.

Did you try other dropout probabilities? Less layers?

Comment: @JakubBartczuk i added some network sizes i have added below and dropout probability's i have tried the dropout probability's all result in the same MSE getting to 1.... E-4 and no higher

Comment: I don't understand. You previously wrote that your MSE is 0.1. MSE of 1E-4 is way better

Comment: BTW you can always try to use smaller dropout.

Comment: @JakubBartczuk i trained it overnight for around 10000000 iterations (stopped it when i woke up but it was just over that) and got it that low. I will try 2% dropout for a few hours and tell you how it goes.

Comment: I still don't understand... What is the final MSE? Could you post error rate across iterations?

Comment: @JakubBartczuk should i use dropout on the input layer or is that a bad idea? I am still new to neural networks.

Comment: It's hard to tell - for example you didn't say what's the training set size... If you're new to NNs then I don't think it's a good idea to ask such questions on cross-validated before taking a serious course on neural networks - in practice they require a lot of tuning and tricks, and it's better to learn it from a course/book than loosely related cross-validated questions

Comment: @JakubBartczuk i added the information for the training set size, i forgot to add the testing data size but its 50.

Comment: This output is unreadable... Please format it in code snippets and annotate accordingly - some people even flag posts with such pictures as badly formatted

Comment: @JakubBartczuk Hi, i noticed that i changed the activation function from tanh to sigmoid and now get the results noted above, note the one with dropout hasn't finished training and will update that once done.

Comment: I meant putting logs in code blocks and formatting them. Still unreadable...

Comment: Notice that in some neural network related library the Dropout layers get a parameter that defines the *keep* chance and others get a parameter that defines the *drop* chance. Make sure you didn't get them mixed.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t know if you have specific design issues for your problem, but your training data size of 240 is usually too small to train an accurate model for 100-dimension input. You may easily get either overfitting if your network consists of several layers - with a lot more parameters than samples, or underfitting with too shallow network - with inadequate capacity and/or nonlinearity to model your problem. Neither of them can bring you good test result - as a measure of your model’s generalization.